# Write data to a CSV on the fly and download the file using fast api

Tags: python, dataframe, fastapi

I am getting corrupted data when I am downloading the file using the api:

```
file_name = 'download' 
prepared_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
path_to_excel = os.path.join(dir_to_download, file_name)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_to_excel, engine='xlsxwriter')
prepared_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Downloading file using **`FileResponse`**:

```
FileResponse(path=path_to_excel, filename=file_name, media_type='text/xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to save the file locally, you can save it on the fly with help of `StringIO`/`BytesIO`. Personally, I recommend you to use CSV instead of XLSX format in such case, it will work faster.

```
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/file", response_description='xlsx')
async def xlsx_file():
    frame = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
    output = BytesIO()

    with pd.ExcelWriter(output) as writer:
        frame.to_excel(writer)

    headers = {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="example.xlsx"'
    }
    return StreamingResponse(iter([output.getvalue()]), headers=headers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app)
```